# In machine learning, for a kernel function k, is sqrt(k) also a valid kernel function?

Tags: machine-learning, kernel-trick

For some kernel function k which by definition has a symmetric and positive semidefinite kernel matrix K, is the new kernel function sqrt(k) also a valid kernel function?

If we use Mercer's theorem, it is easy to show that the new kernel matrix is symmetric. The confusion is regarding checking if the new kernel matrix is also positive semidefinite, since the root computed at each element can also have negative values.

Comment: *"since the root computed at each element can also have negative values"* what do you mean by this? Do you consider the root to have two values? E.g. $\sqrt{9} = -3 \text{ and } \sqrt{9} = 3$

Comment: Exactly. Each entry at (i, j) in the kernel matrix K is sqrt(a) for some real number a. Now this sqrt(a) and be either +b or -b.

Comment: If you use $\sqrt{k}$ as kernel then why would you use the negative value? A kernel needs to be non-negative. Also, it is not typical to see the square root as having negative values as output. The equation $y^2 = x$ has two solutions for $y$ given $x$, but $y = \sqrt{x}$ has only one solution.

Comment: how do you propose to define the square root of the kernel if some entries of K are negative?

Answer (score 10):

#### Counterexample

An example of a positive definite kernel is $K = \mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{y}$.

But when we consider the following $x_i$

$$x_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 17 \\ 9 \\ 7 \\0 \end{bmatrix} \qquad x_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 9 \\ 17 \\ 0 \\ 7 \end{bmatrix} \qquad x_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 7 \\ 0 \\ 12 \\4 \end{bmatrix} \qquad x_4 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 7 \\ 4 \\12 \end{bmatrix} $$

Then the following matrix is positive definite $$ \mathbf{K_{ij}}  = \mathbf{x_i} \cdot \mathbf{x_j} = \begin{bmatrix} 419 & 306 & 203 & 91 \\ 306 & 419 & 91 & 203 \\ 203 & 91 & 209 & 96 \\ 91 & 203 & 96 & 209 \end{bmatrix}$$

because it has all positive eigenvalues.

But the matrix with square root entries has a negative eigenvalue (and also it has a negative determinant).

You can check the computations with this R-code:

```r
> X = matrix(c(17,   9,   7,   0,
+              9,  17,   0,   7,
+              7,   0,  12,   4,
+              0,   7,   4,  12), 4, byrow = TRUE)
> M = X^T %*% X
> eigen(M)
eigen() decomposition
$values
[1] 876.2977 225.0000 153.7023   1.0000

$vectors
           [,1] [,2]       [,3] [,4]
[1,] -0.6287365 -0.5 -0.3235590  0.5
[2,] -0.6287365  0.5 -0.3235590 -0.5
[3,] -0.3235590 -0.5  0.6287365 -0.5
[4,] -0.3235590  0.5  0.6287365  0.5

> eigen(M^0.5)
eigen() decomposition
$values
[1] 55.8634685  8.6007080  6.3536679 -0.9652008

$vectors
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
[1,] -0.5649924  0.4539114 -0.4251866  0.5421849
[2,] -0.5649924 -0.4539114 -0.4251866 -0.5421849
[3,] -0.4251866  0.5421849  0.5649924 -0.4539114
[4,] -0.4251866 -0.5421849  0.5649924  0.4539114

>
```

Comment: Note that showing that a symmetric matrix has a positive determinant is *not* enough to show that it is positive definite-p.d. means that all of the eigenvalues are positive, which is a much stronger condition. In this case, though, the matrix K is in fact p.d., because it is of the form M^TM

Comment: @MikeHawk you are right, I was mixing things up with Sylvester's criterion which is about determinants (but different). Anyway a negative determinant is sufficient proof that the matrix is not pd.